# Rails: How to redirect from home page and keep possibility to open it from navbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How i can redirect logged users from home page and same time keep possibility to open home page by clicking it in the menu.

I using high_voltage gem and my pages controller looks like:

```
private

def redirect_logged_user
  case params[:id]
  when 'home'
    if user_signed_in?
      redirect_to books_path
    end
  end
end
```

So when user open http://example.com and he is logged he will redirected to books page (http://example.com/books), but same time i need to keep possibility to open home page if user click "home" at the navigation bar.

Comment: Do you mean you want to redirect them if it is their first login or always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such kind of functionality you need to pass extra variable while calling from navigation bar and in your `redirect_logged_user` method you need to manage redirect accordingly.

```
<% link_to Home, home_path(:nav => true)%>
```

This will pass extra parameter nav=true with request `http://example.com?nav=true`
Now you method should be like :

```
def redirect_logged_user
  case params[:id]
  when 'home'
    if user_signed_in? && !params[:nav]
      redirect_to books_path
    end
  end
end
```